# Collapsing toolbar with shared element transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, shared-element-transition

I would like to have a shared element that goes from one fragment to second fragments collapsing toolbar. I guess the base activity should have the collapsing toolbar.

Here is image for better imagination:

[image: Animation]

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you are handling fragments through viewpager ,you could listen to addOnPageChangeListener and depending on the page you are just pass the element from one fragment to another,and the toolbar containing the shared element could also be made visibl depending upon the current page.

And if you are just replacing the fragment try saving the element and on replacing the old fragment set the element on toolbar. 
Hope it helps